# How can I write text that the clipboard sees but isn't visible?

Tags: html, css, image, text, clipboard

Until recently I'd been using style=display:none on an image to do this with its alt text. That method is no longer working, so what can I do?

Comment: I am not sure what your intention is, but did you consider writing html comments into your clipboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<span style="font-size: 0;">i should still be copied</span>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/bYzNM/).

Answer (score 2):

```
/* Fully transparent text */
color:rgba(0,0,0,0)
```

Comment: That will still leave a considerable gap where the text was though?

Comment: @alex True; I didn't see that was a requirement by the OP.

Comment: I just assumed because of what `display: none` would do. This  works OK if that isn't an issue so +1

Comment: For this function there's also visibility:hidden, but thanks for the input!