# What text can be copied but not searched for?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, text

I previously used the alt attribute of images to produce text that could reach the clipboard:

The style attribute is capable of hiding text, but hidden text still exists and can be found using indexOf, control-F and the like.

Is there another way to include text when a selection is copied?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I write text that the clipboard sees but isn't visible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838917/how-can-i-write-text-that-the-clipboard-sees-but-isnt-visible)

Comment: This question is about the searchablilty of text, not visibility.

Comment: I don't understand how text can be copied but not searched for. If you can copy it, it lives in the DOM. Search parses the DOM.

Comment: @Nick: Because attributes of elements aren't on the DOM? If I knew better I wouldn't ask. What I do know is that the clipboard used to grab the alt attribute of images with undefined src value when the surrounding text was copied.

Comment: I think we need the content of what you're trying to hide, `display: none;` still works fine on spanned text, i.e. the hidden spanned text gets copied and pasted.. and the text in the span is not found by searching the page,  Is that not what you're after. do you have to use the image at all?

Comment: If you mean `<span style="display:none">Can't find me!</span>` innerHTML isn't reaching the clipboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the alt attribute is the instrumental piece here:

```
<img alt="Can't find me!"/>
```

The above element should display the alt text, however control-F and indexOf() methods will be unable to find it.

I don't need this text to be hidden, just unavailable to indexOf() but it won't hurt to mention that style="display:none;" will prevent this from working (the text will not reach the clipboard). If you need to hide the text, instead use style="font-size:0;", as I found earlier in [How can I write text that the clipboard sees but isn't visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838917/how-can-i-write-text-that-the-clipboard-sees-but-isnt-visible)

Comment: I don't quite manage to get this working on Chrome actually: http://jsfiddle.net/r7Sza/. If I copy the whole, all I get is `aa`.

Comment: Yes, it appears this only works in Firefox, so alternatives are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I posted this answer yesterday but deleted it because I didn't think I'd understood your question properly. But given the additional info you've posted, I actually think it may be what you're looking for. (if it isn't what you're looking for, please let me know and I'll delete it again)

Something like this:

```
This is some <span style='display:inline-block; width:0px; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap;'>copy me!</span>random text.
```

Should display `This is some random text.` on the browser, but when copied and pasted into Notepad, it should give you `This is some copy me!random text.`

Comment: @pimvdb - meh, you're right. It does work in Firefox, Opera and IE, but I hadn't tested it in Chrome or Safari.

Comment: if this is indeed a solution the OP wants (I still don't understand the question either ;)) - then - `span {position: absolute; clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); clip: rect (1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);}` - does work in Chrome too, neither version make the text "unsearchable" though so I'm not sure this in the answer being looked for either :) - `display: none` works fine on a span for me

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I can still find it using control-F.