# How does Financial Times add a disclaimer when pasting text?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, usability, user-experience

Here is an example of what happens when pasting text from Financial Times, the top paragraph is added.

Thanks in advance!

Example:

> Please respect FT.com's ts&cs and copyright policy which allow you to: share links; copy content for >personal use; & redistribute limited extracts. Email ftsales.support@ft.com to buy additional rights >or use this link to reference the article - http://www.ft.com/cms/s/0/792f1aec->9600-11e0-8256-00144feab49a.html#ixzz1PFrYZiD0
>
> Goldman Sachs gave a paid internship to a top Libyan official’s relative while the bank was carrying >out lossmaking trades on behalf of the country’s sovereign wealth fund, the Financial Times has learnt.

Comment: Do you mean, "pasting text **onto** the Financial Times", or "pasting text that was copied **from** the Financial Times"?

Comment: try, it's from the FT :)

Comment: That's very interesting indeed. I don't have an answer, but intend to find one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026335/how-to-add-extra-info-to-copied-web-text

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098068/what-text-can-be-copied-but-not-searched-for/6098284#6098284 for an answer I posted recently which shows one way of achieving this sort of thing using pure CSS.

Comment: To answer your specific question: FT use a service called Tynt that both adds and tracks the copy action by using JS to add hidden content to the user's selection. That leads to a more general question: how would I do that? That's one I've already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026335

Comment: You can try the solution of this post, it worked for me like a breeze : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238142/get-the-users-copied-text-in-jquery-and-rewrite-the-paste

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Webmaster use Javascript for that.

Check file http://media.ft.com/j/FTTrack2.js

```
FT.Tynt={
    initTynt:function(){
        var Tynt=Tynt||[];
        Tynt.push('cqolxGrS4r34rIadbiUt4I');
        Tynt.i={
            "cc":"0",
            "b":true,
            "ap":"Please respect FT.com's <a href='http://www.ft.com/servicestools/help/terms'>ts&amp;cs</a> and <a href='http://www.ft.com/servicestools/help/copyright'>copyright policy</a> which allow you to: share links; copy content for personal use; &amp; redistribute limited extracts. Email ftsales.support@ft.com to buy additional rights or use this link to reference the article -",
            "t":true
        }
```

Answer (score 10):

As already previously mentioned, modifying the clipboard data is either restricted to specific browsers or requires the user to grant access to modifying the clipboard. A work around to this you could

1. Add an event handler to the `oncopy` event
2. Find the selection
3. Prepend/append content to the content
4. Modify the selection range to include the appended/prepended content
5. Wait for the copy action to push through
6. Remove the appended/prepended content

I fiddled about with this method and created a plugin which does just that. Still a preliminary version and only tested on FF4/Chrome 11/IE8 so far (and IE definetly needs to have some more work done). Some of the nice things you can do with this method is that you could easily for example wrap forum post quotes in `[quote=USER]content[/quote]` and assign the user based on which post is copied. By default, the script always selects the DOM styling, but not the actual HTML, so if you for example copy **bold** content, it would be bold if pasted into a rich text editor, but just text if used in text only editors (removing the html tags).

Prepending content is significantly easier with this method, compared to appending, in which case I still am not sure whether it is fully functional. For IE, you could directly modify the clipboard, but there are some issues for example when selecting the whole page, or if you want to toggle the rich copy content. Haven't had the chance to do any further browser testing, but this appears to be at least a working solution for newer browsers.

Example: http://hertzen.com/experiments/jquery.plugin.clipboard/

Another example: http://hertzen.com/experiments/jquery.plugin.clipboard/thread.html

Source code: https://github.com/niklasvh/jquery.plugin.clipboard

Answer (score 6):

You implement a handler for [the `oncopy` event.](http://help.dottoro.com/ljwexqxl.php) By manipulating the [`clipboardData` object](http://help.dottoro.com/ljxundda.php), you can change the copied text.

Comment: Modifying the clipboardData only works with IE, and the workaround shown there for FF throws a security exception on later versions of FF at least.

Comment: That only works in older IEs (it doesn't in 8 or 9) and is a security bug - javascript shouldn't have the ability to manipulate clipboard data.

Answer (score 4):

This is something you can achieve via a jQuery plugin named [jquery copy](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/copy). Here's an example using the p selector.

```
$("p").click(function() {
    $.copy($(this).text() + " Disclaimer goes here!");
});
```

Comment: That's predefined selection that's copied. With FS you can perform your own selection and it prepends the disclaimer on it. (+.$copy is a plugin, and not part of jquery)

Answer (score 4):

They use JavaScript which can be found in the following file:

http://media.ft.com/j/FTTrack2.js